# Scope clashes for fields & local variables

Tags: c#, scope

See below code snippets

```
class scopes
{
  static int j=20;
  Console.WriteLine(j);
    public static void Main()
   {
       int j=30;
       Console.WriteLine(j);
       return;
   }
}
```

For above code , variable hiding is supported
see below code

```
public static int Main()
{
    int j = 20;
    for (int i=0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        int j = 30;    //can't do this
        Console.WriteLine(j + i);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here for above code variable hiding is not supported.

What is the reason behind this?

Comment: Your first example doesn't compile, either.

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(j);` in first example is typo i guess.

Comment: minor terminology thing - if you had to call the first example (the one that compiles) by a name, surely it would be *field* hiding, not *variable* hiding; the *variable* is never hidden...

Comment: @Ravindra - Agree with Marc, its field hiding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the first case, there is at least a defined way to disambiguate between the two things, i.e. the `this.` prefix - inside the method, `this.j` is the field, where-as `j` is the member. As for why this is supported: speculation, but *probably* so that adding a field to the class (which could be in a different code file in the case of `partial` classes) doesn't cause random methods to start throwing compiler errors. Note that the meaning in of `j` in the method is identical before and after the field `j` is added.

In the second case, this is not a concern: adding locals can only impact the single local method, and there is no disambiguation syntax (i.e. which `j` do we mean), and no risk of accidental breakage **from unrelated code**.